# mention user from string(name#discriminator) discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an user in str format, for example:

```
me#0000
```

I want to convert it into a member to be able to do:

```
member.mention
```

I tried:

```
MemberConverter()
```

and:

```
member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=user.split("#")[0], discriminator=user.split("#")[1])
```

both make member NoneType, the name and discriminator are fine.

Comment: have you enabled members intent?

Comment: yes, I do:
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

Comment: then can you please provide more code?

Comment: nvm, apparently it was NoneType because the user was not in the right server, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both the username and discriminator, the best way to get that member would be like this:

```py
member = message.guild.get_member_named("me#0000")
```

**ALSO:**
Make sure you have enabled intents in your bot (`discord.Intents.all()`) **and** in your application in the [Discord Dev Portal](https://discord.com/developers)

Comment: still not working, intents are enabled in the portal and in the code, and also your solution make member as NoneType... :(

Comment: nvm, apparently it was NoneType because the user was not in the right server, thanks for the help